# typescript wrap Array Generic type

Tags: arrays, generics, typescript

I'd like to wrap the generic Array in typescript.
  We have code as below:

```
    _bindings: Array<BindingDescription>;
```

What I want is to have a wrapper around Array so I can use

```
    _bindings: BindingDescriptionCollection;
```

I'm trying to wrap it as below:

```
    export class BindingDescriptionCollection implements Array<BindingDescription> {}
```

But it need to implements all the functions and properties in Array.

Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking to add additional functionality or simply just use a cleaner name? If it's the latter, you can use a [type alias](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-aliases):

```
type BindingDescriptionCollection = Array<BindingDescription>;
```

Comment: @Emma Great! Feel free to click the checkmark next to an answer if your question has been fully resolved - this lets people know you found an answer you're satisfied with.

Answer (score 2):

> But it need to implements all the functions and properties in Array.
>   Is there any easier way?

You can use `extend` to inherit the functionality:

```
interface BindingDescription{}
class BindingDescriptionCollection extends Array<BindingDescription> {}
```

Comment: No. I've tried this way in the first place. I will get an Error: "A class may only extend another class". Array<T> itself is defined as an interface.

Comment: @Emma you need to use Typescript 1.6. It's only in [beta](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/02/announcing-typescript-1-6-beta-react-jsx-better-error-checking-and-more.aspx) right now though.